# Check if a list on strings contains a string from another list

Tags: java

I have two lists of string, 'a' and 'b'. Now I need to check if any of the strings in 'b' contain or equal to any of the strings in 'a'.

This is what I've tried

```
for (String string : a) {
    if (!contains(string)) {
        // add 'string' to another list. 
    }
}
```

and

```
private boolean contains(String a) {
    for (String string : b) {
        if (b.contains(a)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, this does not seem to work. Please bear in mind that I'm still fairly new to Java so there's a lot of things I still don't understand.

Edit: I return false in purpose, I just changed the variables to make it more understandable for you.

Comment: Try with [Collection#retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) and check the size.

Comment: strings in 'b' contain or equal to any of the strings in 'a'  ---   so if b is {"abc", "def", "him"} and a is {"a"} should the function return true (because "abc" contains "a")?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String s : a) 
  for(String ss : b) 
     if(s.contains(ss)) return true;
return false;
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

!Collections.disjoint(list1, list2);

or

List.retainAll

Answer (score 0):

Try this method `contains()` that check passed `String a` is present in passed `Collcetion b`. If `b` contains string `a`, so return `true` else `false`.

```
private static boolean contains(String a, List<String> b) {
  for (String string : b) {
    if (string.equals(a)) {
      return true;
    }
   }
  return false;
}
```

Example:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("1");
a.add("2");
a.add("3");

List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
b.add("1");
b.add("2");
b.add("4");

for (String string : a) {
  if (!contains(string, b)) {
    System.out.println("String " + string + " is not present in collection b");
  }
}
```

Sysout:

`String 3 is not present in collection b`

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using my method for another thing, it did the exact opposite of what I wanted, but that actually worked out great for me when I combine it with this method!